# A sequence defined by $x(1) = 11, x(2) = 23$ and $x(n) = x(n-1) +12x(n-2)$ for all $n ≥ 3$. Prove for all $n∈ℕ, x(n) = 2\times 4^n - (-3)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Brackets indicate it goes along with the variable, not multiplied except for (-3)

A sequence $\{x(i)\}$ is defined by $x(1) = 11, x(2) = 23$ and $x(n) = x(n-1) +12x(n-2)$ for all $n \geq 3$.

Prove for all $n∈ℕ, x(n) = 2\times4^n - (-3)^n$.

Comment: Hint: use induction. BUT you have to use LaTeX code to format your question. You have to explain what you have done yourself too. ALSO it is NOT linear algebra.

Comment: What tag am I supposed to put it in?

Comment: I changed the tag. Please try to use LaTex in formatting your question. Use dollar sign for instance. I did it this time for you. :-)

Comment: So try to use induction and write the proof yourself.

Comment: @Arash Actually this type of recursion has a beautiful linear algebra representation with a 2x2 matrix: [x(n+2) x(n+1)] = [23 11] * [[1 1] [12 0]]^n.  One approach to proving the invariant would be to look at eigenvector decomposition of the [[1 1] [12 0]] matrix.  Depending on his coursework, the tag might not be an accident.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the condition holds for $x_1$ and $x_2$.
Then we proceed to using the induction hypothesis. We will assume the condition holds for $x_{n-1}$ and for $x_{n-2}$ and then prove that it holds for $x_n$.

\begin{align}
& 2*4^{n-1} - (-3)^{n-1} + 12 (2*4^{n-2}-(-3)^{n-2}) \\
& = \frac14 *2*4^n - \frac 1{-3} (-3)^n + 12(\frac1{16}2*4^n -\frac19(-3)^n) \\
& = \frac14 *2*4^n + \frac 13 (-3)^n + \frac342*4^n -1\frac13(-3)^n) \\
& = 2*4^n - (-3)^n \\
\end{align}

This is called proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x(n)= A r^n$.  Then the recurrence becomes

$$r^2=r+12$$

Solve for $r$, get two solutions $r_1$ and $r_2$.  The general solution is then

$$A r_1^n+B r_2^n$$

Use the initial conditions you stated to find $A$ and $B$.